# How to send multiple contacts by email?

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, gmail

I've searched all over the place and couldn't find a solution.

I want to send around 30 contacts (names + phone numbers) by email, to someone. Now I can't seem to succeed with the feat! What can I do to send a simple list (or a table) containing the name and phone number of an entire group of people (they're already organized in a group).

Offering free cookies and upvotes for any good info!

Comment: I won't consider this an answer but a tip would be to use one of those backup programs to backup your contacts to CSV.  You can then pretty-up the CSV file and filter for the contacts you'd like to send.

Comment: I've though about that, but it can't be that there's no simple solution for this...

Comment: You're actually right.  The very fact that a program can dump all contacts implies theres a way to dump just some.  Its probably a case of there being no app to do this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you need to do if from your phone?

Because if not, you can just use the Gmail desktop interface to do this, I do this quite often and it's fairly easy:

- Go to your contacts (click `Gmail` in the upper left corner)
- Select the contacts you want to export
- Put them in a new group you can call `Tmp` or something random
- Then click on that group and find the `Export` menu item in one of the menus (I think `More actions`)
- Export to Google CSV if the receiver will import them through Gmail as well, otherwise you can consider vCard format. The file will download automatically.
- Compose a new mail and put the newly created file as attachment.
- (If you used Google CSV, the contacts can be imported using the same Contacts interface just by clicking `Import` in one of the menus)

Comment: As a matter of fact, that's exactly what I did 2 days after I asked this question. +1, thank you :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha

Is there any way to do the same from mobile?
Any app that does this task?

Comment: @coder you're asking me this? I'm the one who asked the question to begin with!

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, yes.. just checking if theres any news about it..

Answer (score 0):

Open your sms app
compose a new message
Add text and then choose to add contact
add your contacts here is a message area
copy the text message

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you expand your instructions a little? I think your answer works but it's very hard to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this from my phone just now.

- create a temporary contract group, and add the contacts you wish to export to it.
- change the peoples app settings of "contacts to display" to only show this group
- when viewing the contacts, go to the menu "import/export" option
- select "share visible contacts"

That's it. I hope it works for you.